Exterior multiplication is adjoint/dual operator to interior multiplication in the exterior algebra
I was reading section 1.3.1 of Compact Lie group by Mark R. Sepanski.
Definition 1.30. For $x\in\mathbb R^n$ let the exterior multiplication be the map $\epsilon(x):\wedge^k\mathbb R^n\rightarrow \wedge^{k+1}\mathbb R^n$ given by $\epsilon(x)(y)=x\wedge y$ and the interior multiplication $i(x):\wedge^k\mathbb R^n\rightarrow \wedge^{k-1}\mathbb R^n$ given by $i(x)(y)=\sum_{i=1}^k(-1)^{i+1}(x,y_i)y_1\wedge y_2\wedge\cdots \widehat{y_i}\wedge\cdots y_k$. where $x,y\in\wedge^k \mathbb R^n$ and $\widehat{y_i}$ means to omit the term.
Also, the inner product on $\wedge \mathbb R^n$ is defined as, $$\langle x_1\wedge x_2\wedge\cdots\wedge x_k,y_1\wedge y_2\wedge\cdots\wedge y_l\rangle=\begin{cases}0,&k\neq l\\\det(\langle x_i,y_j\rangle)_{k\times k},&k=l\end{cases}\tag1$$

Question 1: I didn't find any motivation like why we define the inner product using the determinant? It will be a great help if anyone enlighten my with any kind of motivation for this.

Now, the author mentions that $i(x)$ is the adjoint of $\epsilon(x)$ and also that $i(x)=\epsilon(x)^*$ with respect to the inner product on $\wedge^k \mathbb R^n$ above. I tried to show the adjoint by taking the action of each one on $\alpha\in\wedge^k\mathbb R$, $\beta\in\wedge^{k+1}\mathbb R^n$ and want to show:
$$\langle \epsilon(x)(\alpha),\beta\rangle=\langle\alpha,i(x)(\beta)\rangle$$
$\epsilon(x)$ expands the degree by wedging $x$ and $i(x)$ do the opposite. Here, $\langle \epsilon(x)(\alpha),\beta\rangle\stackrel{(i)}{=}\langle x\wedge\alpha,\beta\rangle_{\wedge^{k+1}\mathbb R^n}$ and $\langle \alpha,i(x)(\beta) \rangle\stackrel{(ii)}{=}\langle \alpha,\gamma \rangle_{\wedge^{k}\mathbb R^n}$ where $i(x)$ contracts the degree of $\beta$ and produce $\gamma$.
I feel that we need to consider two cases where $x$ appears in $\beta=x\wedge\rho$ and $x$ doesn't in $\beta$ in $(i)$. But the final inner product does not match. And how do we show the duality?

Question 2: How to show that $\langle x\wedge\alpha,\beta\rangle_{\wedge^{k+1}\mathbb R^n}$ equal to $\langle \alpha,\gamma \rangle_{\wedge^{k}\mathbb R^n}$? And how do we show the duality?


For your first question, note that $(\bigwedge^n \mathbb{R}^n)^*= \mathbb R \cdot \det$

Can you expand your comment a little bit? @julio_es_sui_glace Like for $\omega\in\wedge^n\mathbb R^n$ and $\varphi\in\left(\wedge^n\mathbb R^n\right)^*$ then we have a natural pairing $\langle\varphi,\omega\rangle=\varphi(\omega)$. But in our case both of them from $\wedge\mathbb R^n$. That's why I didn't see it as natural unless we turn one $e^1\wedge e^2\wedge\cdots\wedge e^n$ to $(e_1,e_2,\cdots,e_n)$.

It is natural since det is an alternate n-linear form, which is exactly the vector space $(\bigwedge^n \mathbb R^n)^*$

Also a direct computation works for the adjoins property

As you already know $\bigwedge^k V$ can be obtain as a quotient of $V^{\otimes k}$ by the subspaces generated by the $x_1\otimes \cdots \otimes x_k + \epsilon(\sigma) x_{\sigma(1)} \otimes \cdots x_{\sigma(k)} $ for $(x_j) \in V^k$ and $\sigma \in \mathfrak{S}_k$.
Of course one can limit itself to transpositions since they generate $\mathfrak{S}_k$.
It has thus the following universal property (combining the quotients properties of $V^{\otimes k}$ and $\bigwedge^k V$):

For any alternate k-linear map $f: V^k \to W$, there is a unique linear map
$$\bar{f}: \bigwedge^k V \to W$$
satisfying $\bar f \circ \pi = f$ with $\pi: V^k \to \bigwedge^k V$ the projection map.

In particular $\det: V^{n} \to \mathbb R$ with $n = \dim V$ is an alternate $n$-linear form, thus it can be seen as a linear map $\det : \bigwedge^n V$. Furthermore since $\dim \bigwedge^n V = \binom{n}{n}= 1$, it is the only one, so we often denote $\det(v_1,\dots,v_n) = v_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge v_n$ with the isomorphism given by $e_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge e_n \mapsto 1$ for example.
About question one
What we want to build is a canonical inner product on the algebra $\bigwedge V = \bigoplus_{k=0}^n \bigwedge^k V$ (forget about $\mathbb{R}^n$ if you want to think about canonicity), and we only have at our disposal $\langle \bullet,\bullet \rangle : V \times V \to \mathbb R$ (which you can also see as linear on $V \otimes V$).
The problem is that elements of $\bigwedge V$ are generated by the data of several vectors, so we need to find a multilinear way to intricate both and this way also have to repeat the "alternate" property of the exterior power.
We also need this to respect the graded nature of $\bigwedge V$, for that we intertwine $x_1\wedge \cdots \wedge x_k$ and $y_1\wedge \cdots \wedge y_l$ iff $l=k$.
This means our plan of action should be (for generators $x_1\wedge \cdots \wedge x_k$ and $y_1\wedge \cdots \wedge y_k$:

Compute all the $\langle x_i,y_j\rangle$.
Combine them in a good multilinear alternate way so since we have $k \times k$ data we have one canonical way to do so: use the determinant.

digression
What could we have done if $V$ was not euclidian? The thing is that now we lose the canonical isomorphism $V^* \simeq V$ so we replace all the $y$'s by $y^* \in V^*$ and the scalar product by $\langle y^*,x\rangle = y^*(x)$.
About question 2
We move back to $V = \mathbb{R}^n$ since we don't bother about the canonical concerns from here.
Proving that $\langle \bullet, \bullet \rangle_\wedge$ define a scalar product is not that hard since it is obviously a bilinear map and it preserves the passage to quotient so it is well defined, now what remains is positivity.
Note that the $e_{i_1}\wedge \cdots \wedge e_{i_k} = f_I$ with $I = \{i_1<\cdots<i_k\}$ form an orthonormal family for the bilinear form $\langle \bullet, \bullet \rangle_\wedge$ since
$$
\langle f_I , f_I \rangle_\wedge = \det (I_k) = 1
$$
and for $I \neq J$ of size $k$ there is at least one $i_0 \in I \setminus J$ which means $\forall j \in J, \, \langle e_{i_0},e_j \rangle = 0$, so the matrix $(\langle e_i,e_j \rangle)_{(i,j) \in I\times J}$ has one zero row which means it has a zero determinant.
Since it is a basis of $\bigwedge^k \mathbb R^n$, it is sufficient to ensure positivity and definiteness.

Now to show the adjunction it is not very hard, we only need to use the properties of the determinant. Notice that we only need to show it on generators, so we take $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $\alpha = y_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge y_k \in \bigwedge^{k} \mathbb R^n $ and $\beta = z_0 \wedge \cdots \wedge z_k \in \bigwedge^{k+1} \mathbb R^n$.
$$\begin{align*}
\langle \epsilon(x)(\alpha), \beta\rangle 
&=\langle x \wedge y_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge y_k, z_0 \wedge \cdots \wedge z_k \rangle \\
&= \begin{vmatrix}
\langle x, z_0\rangle & \cdots & \langle x, z_k\rangle \\
\langle y_1, z_0\rangle & \cdots & \langle y_1, z_k\rangle \\
\vdots & & \vdots \\
\langle y_k, z_0\rangle & \cdots & \langle y_k, z_k\rangle \\
\end{vmatrix}\\
&= \sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^{j} \langle x,z_j\rangle
\begin{vmatrix}
\langle y_1, z_0\rangle & \cdots & \langle y_1, z_{j-1}\rangle &\langle y_1, z_{j+1}\rangle &  \cdots & \langle y_1, z_k\rangle \\
\vdots & & \vdots & \vdots && \vdots \\
\langle y_k, z_0\rangle & \cdots & \langle y_k, z_{j-1}\rangle &\langle y_k, z_{j+1}\rangle & \cdots & \langle y_k, z_k\rangle \\
\end{vmatrix}\\
&= \sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^{j} \langle x,z_j\rangle \left\langle \alpha,  z_0\wedge \cdots \wedge \hat{z_j} \wedge \cdots \wedge z_k \right\rangle_\wedge\\
&= \left\langle \alpha, \sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^{j} \langle x,z_j\rangle   z_0\wedge \cdots \wedge \hat{z_j} \wedge \cdots \wedge z_k \right\rangle_\wedge\\
&= \langle \alpha, i(x) (\beta) \rangle_\wedge
\end{align*}$$

Here I developed the determinant on the first row.

Which means that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n,$ $\epsilon(x)$ and $i(x)$ are adjoint endomorphisms of the vector space $\bigwedge \mathbb R^n$.
Idea for a development:
Study how well these two endomorphisms behave with multiplication in the algebra $\bigwedge \mathbb R^n$.

 For each monomial $\alpha$ of $\bigwedge \mathbb R^n$ (which means elements of the form $x_1\wedge \cdots \wedge x_k$), we define their degree $|\alpha| = k$ and we have thus for two monomials $\alpha$ and $\beta$:
 $$\epsilon(x)(\alpha) \wedge \beta = \epsilon(x) (\alpha \wedge \beta) \quad \text{and} \quad  \alpha \wedge \epsilon(x)(\beta) = (-1)^{|\alpha|} \epsilon(x) (\alpha \wedge \beta).$$
 And also
 $$i(x)(\alpha \wedge \beta) = i(x)(\alpha) \wedge \beta + (-1)^{|a|} \alpha \wedge i(x)(\beta).$$
 We say that $\epsilon(x)$ is a graded algebra right terminology to find(I'm sure it exists) of degree $1$ and $i(x)$ a graded algebra derivation of degree $-1$.

 Furthermore, we have the graduated Lie bracket
 $$[\epsilon(x),i(x)] = \epsilon(x) \circ i(x) - (-1)^{|\epsilon(x)| |i(x)|} i(x) \circ \epsilon(x) = \epsilon(x) \circ i(x) + i(x) \circ \epsilon(x)= \operatorname{id}.$$
 which means they are adjoints in the sense of exterior algebra.


Thank you (+1) very much for your excellent answer @julio_es_sui_glace I have a small confusion in the last part. I googled for graded algebra derivation, and realize that in order to be a graded algebra derivation $\epsilon(x)$ should satisfy:$$\epsilon(x)(a \wedge b) = \epsilon(x)(a) \wedge b + (-1)^{|a|} a \wedge \epsilon(x)(b)$$But we have either $\epsilon(x)(a\wedge b)=\epsilon(x)(a)\wedge b$ or $\epsilon(x)(a\wedge b)=(-1)^{|a|}a\wedge\epsilon(x)(b)$, it seems like the Leibniz's law doesn't satisfy here. I couldn't find where am I wrong here. Thanks again.

@Dr.Antidode yes you are right, this is not the right terminology, I will leave a blank since I don't remember there right one, maybe chatgpt knows

The following section define $\Phi:\oplus_{k=0}^\infty\mathbb R^{\otimes k}=T_n(\mathbb R)\rightarrow \operatorname{End}(\wedge \mathbb R^n)$ by $\Phi(x)=L_x:=\epsilon(x)-i(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb R^n$. I understand that it's a natural map between these two algebras but does it is an algebra homomorphism? @julio_es_sui_glace

@Dr.Antidode I'm not sure, you must check $L_x \circ L_y = L_{x \otimes y}$. It is at least a vector space morphism
